# SequenceSplit around empty sequences is inconsistent

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, sequence

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and persisting through 12.3**

---

Only the first one recognizes a zero-length sequence between non-X's.

```
SequenceSplit[{1, 2, X, 3, X, X, 4, 5, X}, s : {X ...} :> s]
SequenceSplit[{1, 2, X, 3, X, X, 4, 5, X}, s : {(X | X) ...} :> s]
SequenceSplit[{1, 2, X, 3, X, X, 4, 5, X}, s : {(X | 5) ...} :> s]
(* {{}, {1}, {}, {2}, {X}, {3}, {X, X}, {4}, {}, {5}, {X}} *)
(* {{1, 2}, {X}, {3}, {X, X}, {4, 5}, {X}} *)
(* {{1, 2}, {X}, {3}, {X, X}, {4}, {5, X}} *)
```

`MatchQ` works as expected.

```
MatchQ[{}, {X ...}]
MatchQ[{}, {(X | X) ...}]
MatchQ[{}, {(X | 5) ...}]
(* True, True, True *)
```

I want to `SequenceSplit` around sequences of the form `{(X | Y | Z)...}` including empty ones; why can't I do this? Is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe you could try: `SequenceSplit[{1, 2, X, 3, X, X, 4, 5, X}, {s : {X ...} :> s, 
  s : {(X | X) ...} :> s}]`

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you are doing.  And it doesn't look like it's working as documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, at least there's a workaround.

```
SequenceSplit[list, {s : {(X | Y | Z)...} :> s, {} -> {}}]
```

Edit: answer from Wolfram Technical Support - "It does appear that SequenceSplit is not behaving properly. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided"